# JSON - Accessing JSON Array and assigning variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

I have the following JSON in a file called census.json:

```
{
    "areas": [
        "UnitedStates", [{
        "STATEORREGION": "United States",
            "1910POPULATION": 92228531,
            "1920POPULATION": 106021568,
            "1930POPULATION": 123202660,
            "1940POPULATION": 132165129,
            "1950POPULATION": 151325798,
            "1960POPULATION": 179323175,
            "1970POPULATION": 203211926,
            "1980POPULATION": 226545805,
            "1990POPULATION": 248709873,
            "2000POPULATION": 281421906,
            "2010POPULATION": 308745538,
            "1910CHANGE": 21,
            "1920CHANGE": 15,
            "1930CHANGE": 16.2,
            "1940CHANGE": 7.3,
            "1950CHANGE": 14.5,
            "1960CHANGE": 18.5,
            "1970CHANGE": 13.3,
            "1980CHANGE": 11.5,
            "1990CHANGE": 9.8,
            "2000CHANGE": 13.2,
            "2010CHANGE": 9.7
    }],
        "Alabama", [{
        "STATEORREGION": "Alabama",
            "1910POPULATION": 2138093,
            "1920POPULATION": 2348174,
            "1930POPULATION": 2646248,
            "1940POPULATION": 2832961,
            "1950POPULATION": 3061743,
            "1960POPULATION": 3266740,
            "1970POPULATION": 3444165,
            "1980POPULATION": 3893888,
            "1990POPULATION": 4040587,
            "2000POPULATION": 4447100,
            "2010POPULATION": 4779736,
            "1910CHANGE": 16.9,
            "1920CHANGE": 9.8,
            "1930CHANGE": 12.7,
            "1940CHANGE": 7.1,
            "1950CHANGE": 8.1,
            "1960CHANGE": 6.7,
            "1970CHANGE": 5.4,
            "1980CHANGE": 13.1,
            "1990CHANGE": 3.8,
            "2000CHANGE": 10.1,
            "2010CHANGE": 7.5
    }],
        "Alaska", [{
        "STATEORREGION": "Alaska",
            "1910POPULATION": 64356,
            "1920POPULATION": 55036,
            "1930POPULATION": 59278,
            "1940POPULATION": 72524,
            "1950POPULATION": 128643,
            "1960POPULATION": 226167,
            "1970POPULATION": 300382,
            "1980POPULATION": 401851,
            "1990POPULATION": 550043,
            "2000POPULATION": 626932,
            "2010POPULATION": 710231,
            "1910CHANGE": 1.2,
            "1920CHANGE": -14.5,
            "1930CHANGE": 7.7,
            "1940CHANGE": 22.3,
            "1950CHANGE": 77.4,
            "1960CHANGE": 75.8,
            "1970CHANGE": 32.8,
            "1980CHANGE": 33.8,
            "1990CHANGE": 36.9,
            "2000CHANGE": 14,
            "2010CHANGE": 13.3
    }], ]
}
```

I am trying to access the different values stored in the array using the following:

```
$.getJSON("../data/census.json", function (json) {
    var censusData = json;
    console.log(censusData.areas);
});
```

This logs all the states to the console as an object, so I then tried to go down another level with:

```
$.getJSON("../data/census.json", function (json) {
    var censusData = json;
    console.log(censusData.areas.UnitedStates);
});
```

but this returns "undefined".  How can I drill down another level?  Ideally I would like to access each states population for a specific year and then assign it to a variable that I can use later.

Comment: you have to iterate it at every level

Comment: Your code will pass JSON.parse or eval but will not work the way you want, it is array of mixed objects: "strings" + "objects". You should to reformat it. You can not access censusData.areas.UnitedStates cause object UnitedStates does not exists it is string "UnitedStates" inside of array 'areas'. But you can view  censusData.areas[0] it will give you string "UnitedStates". If you will iterate inside of censusData.areas it will give you mix of "string", "object", "string", "object" and so on. Conclusion is to reformat this json.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no second level as there are commas instead of colons between the state names and their properties:

```
"Alaska", [{
   "STATEORREGION":"Alaska",
   "1910POPULATION":64356,
   ...
```

This makes the values "Alaska" and the dictionary of properties adjacent elements in a list. It seems what you want is:

```
"Alaska": [{
   "STATEORREGION":"Alaska",
   "1910POPULATION":64356,
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the pattern here is after each string name we have an array of related information:
so you can convert it to an object like

```
var _result = {};
   for ( var i=0;i<arr.length/2;i++){
      _result[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
   }
```

then you can directly access those information by their string names

like this

```
censusData.areas.UnitedStates
```

will return an array after this transformation

Answer (score 0):

your json data is invalid try this,

```
{"areas" : [
  "UnitedStates", [{
    "STATEORREGION":"United States",
    "1910POPULATION":92228531,
    "1920POPULATION":106021568,
    "1930POPULATION":123202660,
    "1940POPULATION":132165129,
    "1950POPULATION":151325798,
    "1960POPULATION":179323175,
    "1970POPULATION":203211926,
    "1980POPULATION":226545805,
    "1990POPULATION":248709873,
    "2000POPULATION":281421906,
    "2010POPULATION":308745538,
    "1910CHANGE":21,
    "1920CHANGE":15,
    "1930CHANGE":16.2,
    "1940CHANGE":7.3,
    "1950CHANGE":14.5,
    "1960CHANGE":18.5,
    "1970CHANGE":13.3,
    "1980CHANGE":11.5,
    "1990CHANGE":9.8,
    "2000CHANGE":13.2,
    "2010CHANGE":9.7
  }],
  "Alabama", [{
    "STATEORREGION":"Alabama",
    "1910POPULATION":2138093,
    "1920POPULATION":2348174,
    "1930POPULATION":2646248,
    "1940POPULATION":2832961,
    "1950POPULATION":3061743,
    "1960POPULATION":3266740,
    "1970POPULATION":3444165,
    "1980POPULATION":3893888,
    "1990POPULATION":4040587,
    "2000POPULATION":4447100,
    "2010POPULATION":4779736,
    "1910CHANGE":16.9,
    "1920CHANGE":9.8,
    "1930CHANGE":12.7,
    "1940CHANGE":7.1,
    "1950CHANGE":8.1,
    "1960CHANGE":6.7,
    "1970CHANGE":5.4,
    "1980CHANGE":13.1,
    "1990CHANGE":3.8,
    "2000CHANGE":10.1,
    "2010CHANGE":7.5
  }],
  "Alaska", [{
    "STATEORREGION":"Alaska",
    "1910POPULATION":64356,
    "1920POPULATION":55036,
    "1930POPULATION":59278,
    "1940POPULATION":72524,
    "1950POPULATION":128643,
    "1960POPULATION":226167,
    "1970POPULATION":300382,
    "1980POPULATION":401851,
    "1990POPULATION":550043,
    "2000POPULATION":626932,
    "2010POPULATION":710231,
    "1910CHANGE":1.2,
    "1920CHANGE":-14.5,
    "1930CHANGE":7.7,
    "1940CHANGE":22.3,
    "1950CHANGE":77.4,
    "1960CHANGE":75.8,
    "1970CHANGE":32.8,
    "1980CHANGE":33.8,
    "1990CHANGE":36.9,
    "2000CHANGE":14,
    "2010CHANGE":13.3
  }]
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to access the data by changing the structure of the JSON to the following:

`{"areas" : [
   [{
    "STATEORREGION":"United States",
    "POPULATION1910":92228531,
    "1920POPULATION":106021568,
    "1930POPULATION":123202660,
    "1940POPULATION":132165129,
    "1950POPULATION":151325798,
    "1960POPULATION":179323175,
    "1970POPULATION":203211926,
    "1980POPULATION":226545805,
    "1990POPULATION":248709873,
    "2000POPULATION":281421906,
    "2010POPULATION":308745538,
    "1910CHANGE":21,
    "1920CHANGE":15,
    "1930CHANGE":16.2,
    "1940CHANGE":7.3,
    "1950CHANGE":14.5,
    "1960CHANGE":18.5,
    "1970CHANGE":13.3,
    "1980CHANGE":11.5,
    "1990CHANGE":9.8,
    "2000CHANGE":13.2,
    "2010CHANGE":9.7
  }],
   [{
    "STATEORREGION":"Alabama",
    "1910POPULATION":2138093,
    "1920POPULATION":2348174,
    "1930POPULATION":2646248,
    "1940POPULATION":2832961,
    "1950POPULATION":3061743,
    "1960POPULATION":3266740,
    "1970POPULATION":3444165,
    "1980POPULATION":3893888,
    "1990POPULATION":4040587,
    "2000POPULATION":4447100,
    "2010POPULATION":4779736,
    "1910CHANGE":16.9,
    "1920CHANGE":9.8,
    "1930CHANGE":12.7,
    "1940CHANGE":7.1,
    "1950CHANGE":8.1,
    "1960CHANGE":6.7,
    "1970CHANGE":5.4,
    "1980CHANGE":13.1,
    "1990CHANGE":3.8,
    "2000CHANGE":10.1,
    "2010CHANGE":7.5
  }],
   [{
    "STATEORREGION":"Alaska",
    "1910POPULATION":64356,
    "1920POPULATION":55036,
    "1930POPULATION":59278,
    "1940POPULATION":72524,
    "1950POPULATION":128643,
    "1960POPULATION":226167,
    "1970POPULATION":300382,
    "1980POPULATION":401851,
    "1990POPULATION":550043,
    "2000POPULATION":626932,
    "2010POPULATION":710231,
    "1910CHANGE":1.2,
    "1920CHANGE":-14.5,
    "1930CHANGE":7.7,
    "1940CHANGE":22.3,
    "1950CHANGE":77.4,
    "1960CHANGE":75.8,
    "1970CHANGE":32.8,
    "1980CHANGE":33.8,
    "1990CHANGE":36.9,
    "2000CHANGE":14,
    "2010CHANGE":13.3
  }]
]
}`

Then I used:

`$.getJSON( "../data/census.json", function( json ) {
  var censusData = json;
  console.log(censusData.areas[0][0].POPULATION1910);
 });`

Also note that I had to change `1910POPULATION` to `POPULATION1910` in order to access it without getting an error.  There may be a better way to do this than changing every key name for every state.

When I want to access the next state I just changed `censusData[0][0]` to `censusData[1][0]` and so on and so forth.

Comment: I was unable to use `1910POPULATION` because when you use dot operators it cannot start with a number or contain a space.

Answer (score -1):

The string `"United States"` is the first element in a list.

The data for The United States is in `censusData.areas[1]`. The structure of the JSON looks a bit strange.